How to Restore Scroll Position on Back Navigation in Next.js 14 App router
Next.JS 14.2.3 App router

I’m trying to implement a feature where the scroll position is restored when navigating back, but it’s not working well.
I’m saving the scroll position in session-storage when navigating away from the page, and trying to restore the scroll position in a useEffect hook when navigating back. However, while the scroll position does restore, it then immediately scrolls to the top due to Next.js’s default behavior. Using setTimeout with a slight delay works, but it visibly scrolls to the top first before restoring the position, which isn’t smooth. Setting a delay of 0 works most of the time and restores smoothly, but it fails occasionally, especially on slower networks.
How can I ensure that the scroll position is restored smoothly and reliably when navigating back?
source code
export default function Page({ id }) {
    ...
        
    useEffect(() => {
        const scrollPos = Number(sessionStorage.getItem('scrollPos'));
        sessionStorage.removeItem('scrollPos');
        setTimeout(() => {
          window.scrollTo(0, scrollPos);
        }, 0);
      }, []);
    
    ...
}


Have you tried using scroll={false} in your links?

yes but back navigation did not work

did you find a solution to this?
